# Serialize model for custom jsonapi resource in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json-api, jsonapi-resources

When I make a request to a custom route in my rails project using `jsonapi-resources`, I get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `each_key' for nil:NilClass

  0) ArticlesController when requesting latest_article succeeds
     Failure/Error: serializer.serialize_to_hash(Article.latest)

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `each_key' for nil:NilClass
     # /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/gemsets/blog-api/bundler/gems/jsonapi-resources-bf4b4cd7d79d/lib/jsonapi/resource_set.rb:37:in `populate!'
     # /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/gemsets/blog-api/bundler/gems/jsonapi-resources-bf4b4cd7d79d/lib/jsonapi/resource_serializer.rb:49:in `serialize_to_hash'
     # ./app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:4:in `latest'
     # /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/gemsets/blog-api/gems/actiontext-6.1.4.4/lib/action_text/rendering.rb:20:in `with_renderer'
     # /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/gemsets/blog-api/gems/actiontext-6.1.4.4/lib/action_text/engine.rb:59:in `block (4 levels) in <class:Engine>'
     # /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/gemsets/blog-api/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
     # /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/gemsets/blog-api/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:27:in `call'
     # /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/gemsets/blog-api/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
     # /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/gemsets/blog-api/gems/railties-6.1.4.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
     # /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/gemsets/blog-api/gems/railties-6.1.4.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
     # /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/gemsets/blog-api/gems/railties-6.1.4.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
     # /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/gemsets/blog-api/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
     # /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/gemsets/blog-api/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
     # /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/gemsets/blog-api/gems/railties-6.1.4.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:539:in `call'
     # /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/gemsets/blog-api/gems/rack-test-1.1.0/lib/rack/mock_session.rb:29:in `request'
     # /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/gemsets/blog-api/gems/rack-test-1.1.0/lib/rack/test.rb:266:in `process_request'
     # /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/gemsets/blog-api/gems/rack-test-1.1.0/lib/rack/test.rb:119:in `request'
     # ./spec/requests/articles_controller_spec.rb:22:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

What am I doing wrong here? And more importantly, how do I fix it?

For the purposes of this question, I have a Rails project with `Article` and `Comment` models. I use `jsonapi-resources` to generate all of the CRUD routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  jsonapi_resources :articles do
    collection do
      get :latest
    end
  end
  jsonapi_resources :comments
end
```

I added a custom `articles/latest` route to return the most recent article. I'm using `JSONAPI::ResourceSerializer` to serialize the `Article` object following [the serializer documentation](https://jsonapi-resources.com/v0.10/guide/serializer.html)

```
class ArticlesController < JSONAPI::ResourceController
  def latest
    serializer = JSONAPI::ResourceSerializer.new(ArticleResource)
    serializer.serialize_to_hash(Article.latest)
  end
end
```

I wrote a spec to duplicate the error:

```
describe 'ArticlesController' do
  let!(:articles) { create_list(:article, 10)}

  context 'when requesting articles' do
    it 'succeeds' do
      get articles_path
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
    end
  end

  context 'when requesting latest_article' do
    it 'succeeds' do
      get latest_articles_path
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
    end
  end
end
```

For anyone that made it this far, I have [a complete MCVE project on my GitHub.](https://github.com/codeguru42/blog-api)

From what I can tell from debugging,  [`serializer.serialize_to_hash`](https://github.com/cerebris/jsonapi-resources/blob/master/lib/jsonapi/resource_serializer.rb#L46-L56) creates a `JSONAPI::ResourceSet` with `resource_set = JSONAPI::ResourceSet.new(source, include_related, options)`.

Here is [`JSONAPI::initialize`](https://github.com/cerebris/jsonapi-resources/blob/master/lib/jsonapi/resource_set.rb#L8-L21):

```
    def initialize(source, include_related = nil, options = nil)
      @populated = false
      tree = if source.is_a?(JSONAPI::ResourceTree)
               source
             elsif source.class < JSONAPI::BasicResource
               JSONAPI::PrimaryResourceTree.new(resource: source, include_related: include_related, options: options)
             elsif source.is_a?(Array)
               JSONAPI::PrimaryResourceTree.new(resources: source, include_related: include_related, options: options)
             end

      if tree
        @resource_klasses = flatten_resource_tree(tree)
      end
    end
```

I don't understand the cases in the `if...elsif` chain, but none of the conditions is true for me, so `tree` is `nil` and so `@resource_classes` is also `nil`.

After this, `serialize_to_hash` calls `resource_set.populate!` which in turn calls `@resource_klasses.each_key`, but `@resource_classes` is `nil`.

My current assumption is that I'm doing something wrong that causes `ResourceSet.initialize` to skip initializing `@resource_klasses`. But I'm not sure how to fix it. Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: @engineersmnky Thanks for your time to look at this. However, I am unable to confirm. When I add `puts Article.latest` to `ArticlesController.latest` and run `'when requesting latest_article'`, I get `#<Article:0x00007fac4325c2d0>` which isn't `nil`.

Comment: @engineersmnky I've added some more details that I found while debugging.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `serialize_to_hash` does not accept an `ActiveRecord` object as an argument. Instead, I need to pass it a resource such as with the following:

```
    serializer.serialize_to_hash(ArticleResource.new(Article.latest, {}))
```

I feel like `jsonapi-resources` could give a meaningful error message here rather than blowing up with `NoMethodError`.